# Failed to build xwiimote-bindings

Tags: 15.04, wii

I'm hoping you guys could help me. 
I'm receiving the following error when I attempt to build the bindings. I have installed xwiimote and libxwiimote-dev. I am using ubuntu 15.04. Do you guys have any idea of what is going on. I'm sorry if this an easy question, I could not find any answers online. Do you expect this to problem with using 15.04?

Link for bindings: https://github.com/dvdhrm/xwiimote-bindings

Thanks!

## Update

I downloaded xwiimote and built it successfully along with xwiimote-bindings. I think the original make script installer could not locate the user-space library in /usr/local/lib . I cannot execute xwiishow from the terminal or import xwiimote in python. Attempts to do both result in errors stating it can locate a shared library which I know is in /usr/local/lib

This is likely an easy fix, but I do not have the background. If anyone can give a suggestion it would be appreciated. Thanks!

### Attempting to Exectute xwiishow

```
wiishow: error while loading shared libraries: libxwiimote.so.2:    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### Attempting to Import xwiimote

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xwiimote
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xwiimote.py", line 28,      in <module>
_xwiimote = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xwiimote.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_xwiimote', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libxwiimote.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, xwiimote puts it's library files in /usr/local/lib instead of /usr/lib. On most systems, that path is not searched for libraries, so your application fails to load.

You can choose to reconfigure with `./configure --prefix=/usr` and rebuild or add the libraries to your load path with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`